# C++ Class Object Counter As Random with Static Member

Tags: c++, object, random, static, counter

First of all I do my researches but because I couldn't learn it in lesson well, other answers weren't usable for me. Now my teacher asks from this code that my counter must be initialized by a static member. And when I create another object in the class it must be count by 1000, 1001, 1002. Also first object I created must have a random number which mustn't be global, after that random number will be count 1 by 1.
And I must use pointer for all of that. You know it is really complicated for me but that's what he wants as he said.
Here's my code which isn't working.

```
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <ctime> 

class Point
{
private:
int x;
int y;
static int count;

public:
Point(int, int);
void objectCount()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    Point::count = rand();
    Point::
    count++;
}

 void print();

};
#endif
```

and my .cpp

```
#include "Point.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Point::Point(int x, int y):x(x), y(y){}


void Point::print()
{
 cout << "(" << x << "," << y << ")" << " " << count << endl;
}
```

Comment: Don't just write "Here's my code which isn't working." Always state what you expect to see and what you actually got as output.

Comment: here's what i expected to output:

(x,y) 54545 (anything random)
after another object as 
(x,y) 54546 here goes... 
and i got several errors.

Comment: @lalaolala please [edit]  your question and put all clarifications _there_. And where is your `main` function? And how and where do you call `objectCount`?. Please read this: [mcve]

Comment: You should also add this to your question and also provide a working example. Your posted code does not do anything (where is `main()` or how is `objectCount()` called? What about `print()`?)

Comment: And why are you initializing `Point::count` like this `Point::count = rand();` as a random number? Initially the object yount should be zero, shouldn't it?

Comment: "And I must use pointer for all of that" what does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat unclear what you're asking, but you probably want something like this:

```
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <ctime> 

class Point
{
private:
  int x;
  int y;
  static int count;

public:
  Point(int, int);
  int objectCount()
  {
    return count++;
  }

  void print();
  static int initializeCount();    
};
#endif
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Point.h"
using namespace std;

int Point::count = Point::initializeCount();

int Point::initializeCount()
{
  srand((unsigned)time(0));
  return rand();
}

Point::Point(int x, int y) :x(x), y(y)
{
  objectCount();
}    

void Point::print()
{
  cout << "(" << x << "," << y << ")" << " " << count << endl;
}

int main()
{
  Point p1(1,2);
  p1.print();

  Point p2(2,2);
  p2.print();
}
```

Comment: thank you so much but i shouldn't initialize global how can I do in the function?

Comment: @lalaolala I slightly modified the code. I'm not sure what you mean by your comment.